# Restrict page access only to servers

Tags: file-permissions, htaccess

I am running a cron job to excecute a  file  that should be accessed only by the server   not others.my website is hosted by webhosting company and I have access to cpanel..
What should be done?
I cannot use htacces deny all command has this will restrict the access of the files to cron 
job

Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the server handles it, if it is with php xxx.php then you can  add the following to the top.

```
if(php_sapi_name() != 'cli'){ die(); }
```

The web server will no longer be able to access that page, but PHP-CLI will. I hope this helps

Comment: But I am not sure what is the purpose of using cli..is that cornjobs are run by cli..

Comment: Typically yes. If you run through a webserver, it will either be something like the apache module or fcgi. If you run via the command line with the "php" command, you are using "php-cli" :) cli is "command line interface". I hope this clarifies it

Comment: ok thanks.. I got it what CLI means.but I want to know is it secure.. and nobody can access the page..easy there a better way to do this ..

Comment: CLI can only be accessed through the shell, if the user has shell then that is the least of your concerns. The script will stop execution if you add what I added above if it is not loaded via the cli

Comment: I am  scheduling the job from the cpanel..I wont use cli ..

Comment: cpanel will. Test it!